# corrupted double-linked list after use fclose();

Tags: c, fclose, ansi-c

I have got problem in my program. 
After I use function `fclose()` I got error:

> "*** Error in `./server': corrupted double-linked list: 0x000000000251a230 ***
>   Przerwane (zrzut pamięci)"

If i delete `fclose()` function everythink is OK.
This is code of my fuction:

```
FILE *fHandler;
struct udp_message **returnArray;
struct udp_message *message;
char *line = NULL;
uint32_t linesNum;
uint32_t i = 0;
size_t length; 
ssize_t read;

fHandler = fopen(filePath, "r");
if (fHandler == NULL) {
    perror("ERROR");
    return NULL;
}

returnArray = malloc(sizeof(struct udp_message *)*CONSOLE_BUFFER);
message = malloc(sizeof(struct udp_message));

while ((read = getline(&line, &length, fHandler)) != -1) {
    message = (struct udp_message *)line;
    if (message->messageTime < aboveTime) {
        continue;
    }

    returnArray[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct udp_message));
    memcpy(returnArray[i++], message, sizeof(struct udp_message));
}

memcpy(messageNum, &i, sizeof(i));
fclose(fHandler);

return returnArray;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this part of your code-

```
message = malloc(sizeof(struct udp_message));       /* <--- 1 */

while ((read = getline(&line, &length, fHandler)) != -1) {
   message = (struct udp_message *)line;            /*  <--- 2.  */
   if (message->messageTime < aboveTime) {
       continue;
   }
```

You allocate memory to `message` (see point `1.`) , but then in `while` loop you make it point to `line`  (point `2.`).

*So you loose reference to previously allocated memory (**and both these pointers point to same memory location**), and hence if you* `free` *them ,it will `free` the same memory causing double* `free` *of same memory location.*

So , if you want to make `message` to point `line` , then don't allocate memory to `message`.

Comment: @DanielHornik Welcome :-)

Comment: You have a good point, but reading the udp message with `getline` is still inconsistent with the rest of the code, and the loop does not test if `i` becomes too large. Chances are the code is not really *working*, it just does not crash anymore.

Comment: @chqrlie That is true , as value of `CONSOLE_BUFFER` is unknown to us ,therefore without a check for `i`  could result in out of bound access causing undefined behaviour .

Answer (score 0):

May be worth checking object is not null

```
if(fHandler != NULL)
    fclose(fHandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely you can read your binary UDP messages with `getline`.  There is a chance the `while` loop iterates more than `CONSOLE_BUFFER` times and you write beyond the end of the `returnArray`, corrupting the heap internal structures.  `fclose()` frees the buffer associated with the stream, `free` crashes because of the heap corruption.

Incidentally, `memcpy(messageNum, &i, sizeof(i));` is probably incorrect.  You did not post the function prototype, but you should set the number of messages stored in `returnArray` with `*messageNum = i;`, especially if the type is not `uint32_t *`.